# Can we make the chatbot say greeting first, not just as a reaction

Tags: c#, botframework

I am developing a chatbot using Microsoftt Bot Framework and LUIS cognitive services.
I want a initial welcome message something like "Hello user how are you!" as soon as my bot starts.

anything can be done here in MessageController

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation($"Type={activity.Type} Text={activity.Text}");

            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                //await Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new ContactOneDialog());

                await Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () =>
                new ExceptionHandlerDialog<object>(new ShuttleBusDialog(), displayException: true));

                //await Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new ShuttleBusDialog());
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to explore sending the message as part of the `ConversationUpdate` event. Update your `HandleSystemMessage` method so it looks like the following:

```
    private async Task HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            ConnectorClient client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

            var reply = message.CreateReply();

            reply.Text = "Hello user how are you?"

            await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Am getting the reply repeatedly two times.Any idea on where am wrong?

Comment: @MohanvelV check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823446/when-user-sends-message-to-my-bot-he-receives-welcome-message-but-when-user-re

Answer (score 1):

In the new version HandleSystemMessage is no more async and it returns an Activity, so this is what worked for me:

```
 private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            if (message.MembersAdded.Any(o => o.Id == message.Recipient.Id))
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
                Activity reply = message.CreateReply("I am your service provider virtual assistant, How can I help you today? ");
                connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            }

        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Note the following things:

1. Since HandleSystemMessage is not async you cannot "await" to reply.
2. Use the recipient id check to avoid duplicated welcome messages

Answer (score 0):

Why modify the `HandleSystemMessage` method, when you could simply handle it right in the `Post` method?

Thus, you don't have to mess with creating a new `connector` and using the unfamiliar `connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply)` method.

You can **simply start your root dialog**, same as you would do in reply to a message:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        // ... some code ...

        // this will also handle the beginning of the conversation - 
        // that is when activity.Type equals to ConversationUpdate
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message 
            || activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Because ConversationUpdate activity is received twice 
            // (once for the Bot being added to the conversation, and the 2nd time - 
            // for the user), we have to filter one out, if we don't want the dialog 
            // to get started twice. Otherwise the user will receive a duplicate message.
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate && 
               !activity.MembersAdded.Any(r => r.Name == "Bot"))
                return response;

            // start your root dialog here
            await Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () =>
            new ExceptionHandlerDialog<object>(new ShuttleBusDialog(), displayException: true));
        }
        // handle other types of activity here (other than Message and ConversationUpdate 
        // activity types)
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used "WebChat" channel, the below code worked fine. ChatBot could able to initiate the greeting message and also there was no duplicates!

```
case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
IConversationUpdateActivity update = activity;
var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());
if (update.MembersAdded != null && update.MembersAdded.Any())
{
    foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
    {
        if (newMember.Id == activity.Recipient.Id)
        {
            var reply = activity.CreateReply();
            reply.Text = $"Welcome {newMember.Name}!";
            await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        }
    }
}
break;
```