# BotBuilder backchannel event data into session

Tags: botframework

TLDR: How can I initialise my conversations with data sent from the backchannel and use that information throughout the conversation with a user?

Using [Microsoft botbuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder), a "[backchannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel)" mechanism is provided with which I can send data to and from the bot.

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48261204/769237) I am using the backchannel method to send a conversationStarted event to the bot in order to start a conversation as you might expect.

Upon receiving the event, I start a dialog which fires off my proactive messages to the user.

```
bot.on('event', event => {
  if (event.name === 'conversationStarted') {
    bot.beginDialog(event.address, determineWhichDialogToStart(event))
  }
})
```

I can then use middleware or event listeners to intercept this event and see its contents. Sure enough I can see the event

```
{ type: 'event',
  name: 'conversationStarted',
  text: '',
  myMetaProperty: 'foobar',
  attachments: [],
  entities: [],
  address:
   { id: '8f5d3952-df3b-4340-89b4-97360f8d4965',
     channelId: 'emulator',
     user: { id: '33abc508-86d7-49c1-aa68-00a3491fda12' },
     conversation: { id: '4e8a943d-6a45-41f2-aa11-6671cc1ca4f3' },
     bot: { id: 'bot' },
     serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:3010/' },
  source: 'emulator',
  agent: 'botbuilder',
  user: { id: '33abc508-86d7-49c1-aa68-00a3491fda12' } }
```

But the events I can listen to to see this event, don't have access to the session because the message hasn't yet been dispatched to one it seems.

If I use the `botbuilder` middleware, or the `routing` event, I then see that it's been turned into a message rather than an event, and has lost my meta data passed to the event. (see `myMetaProperty`)

```
{ type: 'message',
  agent: 'botbuilder',
  source: 'emulator',
  sourceEvent: {},
  address:
   { id: '8f5d3952-df3b-4340-89b4-97360f8d4965',
     channelId: 'emulator',
     user: { id: '33abc508-86d7-49c1-aa68-00a3491fda12' },
     conversation: { id: '4e8a943d-6a45-41f2-aa11-6671cc1ca4f3' },
     bot: { id: 'bot' },
     serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:3010/' },
  text: '',
  user: { id: '33abc508-86d7-49c1-aa68-00a3491fda12' } }
```

I tried getting access to the session in my `receive` event/middleware per the [comment here on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4035#issuecomment-357305799) but whilst I get access to *a* session, it's not *the* session.

```
bot.on('receive', event => {
  bot.loadSessionWithoutDispatching(event.address, (error, session) => {
    session.conversationData.myMetaProperty = event.myMetaProperty
  })
})
```

This actually ends up starting a new session - having looked into the `loadSession`/`loadSessionWithoutDispatching`, they both lead to `startSession` and therefore me adding data to the session is lost when i try to use it in a dialog

```
bot.dialog('example', [
  (session, args, next) => {
    console.log(session.conversationData.myMetaProperty) // nope
    console.log(session.cantUseThisEither) // nope
    session.send('foo')
    next()
  }
])
```

Just to reiterate the question now that there's been a bit of background, how can I initialise my conversations with data sent from the backchannel and use that information throughout the conversation with a user?

Comment: Did you figure out the solution to this? Im currently dealing with the same issue.

Comment: I just posted an answer outlining what I ended up doing. Hope it helps. @AlexK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up starting a generic dialog which sets up my session and then moves onto the root dialog.

```
bot.on('event', event => {
  if (event.name === 'conversationStarted') {
    bot.beginDialog(event.address, 'initialise-conversation', {
      myMetaProperty: event.myMetaProperty
    });
  }
});

bot.dialog('initialise-conversation', (session, args, next) => {
  session.conversationData.myMetaProperty = args.myMetaProperty

  session.beginDialog('/');
});
```

Then whenever I need `myMetaProperty` throughout my conversation I can get it from `session.conversationData`

--

In response to the comment below, here's some additional information which may help someone.

The shape of the event you receive on the bot must contain an `address` obviously. For example here's the one I send to my bot.

```
{ myMetaProperty: 'foo',
  name: 'conversationStarted',
  type: 'event',
  address:
   { id: '4q5aaBw77aNGGvrpkeji8A',
     channelId: 'custom-directline',
     user: { id: 'c214imy6PCJZY4G1x2AXSD' },
     conversation: { id: 'bGvMBjEmFTg3DMxsbvJGjH' },
     bot: { id: 'bot' },
     serviceUrl: 'https://localhost:3010/' },
  source: 'custom-directline',
  agent: 'botbuilder',
  user: { id: 'c214imy6PCJZY4G1x2AXSD' } }
```

Start by ensuring that you're sending the address. The key bits of information for routing messages back to an individual are the user and conversation objects.

For example, if you're sending information using the backchannel of the botframework webchat you'd do it as follows.

```
var user = { id: uuidv4() };
var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({...});

botConnection.postActivity({
    type: 'event',
    from: user,
    name: 'conversationStarted',
    myMetaProperty: 'foo',
}).subscribe();

BotChat.App({
    user: user,
    botConnection: botConnection,
}, document.getElementById("bot"));
```

This will be picked up by the event listener described above.

Another thing to note is that the emulator (and possibly other clients/channels send a `conversationUpdate` event which I just passed onto my `conversationStarted` event when I was using it. Here's the listener to do that for reference in case it's useful.

```
  bot.on('conversationUpdate', message => {
    message.membersAdded &&
      message.membersAdded
        .filter(identity => identity.id === message.address.bot.id)
        .forEach(identity => bot.emit('conversationStarted', message));
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the update on what you did. The issue we are having is once we begin the dialog the session within the dialog seems to "loose context" (not sure how to word it). Using your example above, attempting to do session.send() or any other functions that exist on the session object do not seem to work, the message never sends to user who triggered the event. Thanks again for posting this!

Comment: How exactly are you sending your event to the bot? Are you sending it using the backchannel on the client? I have a bespoke directline implementation so mine is a bit different but I've had it working in various ways now so I'm sure I can help. I've added what the event should roughly look like to my answer with some other points which might help.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the backchannel. Mine actually looks exactly like the one you just posted, except for a different event name.

Comment: when you log the event received on the bot does the object look as expected?

Comment: The event object does look as expected. One question, when the bot is doing a session.send and sending to the address of the event, would that actually send a message when it's replying to an event address?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data via [`beginDialog(address: IAddress, dialogId: string, dialogArgs?: any, done?: (err: Error) => void): void;`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L4078), you can pass the data you want to send as the third parameter in this function.

You can refer to the source code at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/bots/UniversalBot.ts#L243 for more details.