# Infinite loop inside RootDialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a problem with infinite loop inside RootDialog. What I'm trying to achieve here is to make a chatbot that sends a welcome message when user joins the conversation. No more interaction, just a single message on ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate - that's all.

Nothing fancy in the code:

**MessageController.cs**

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
}
```

**RootDialog.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;

[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Message");
        context.Done(this);
    }
}
```

**The results:**

[image: Result for Bot Emulator]

[image: Result from Bot Directory - different message, but code is the same]

As you can see it never really exits the RootDialog - or the RootDialog is being called over and over. I've been looking for a answer for quite a while and couldn't find anything useful. The documentation points to using context.Done(this) as a way of ending the dialog, but obviously it's not working here.

I couldn't find any resonable explanation why it's happening, I'd be more than happy for any suggestions.

Comment: How can you tell its an infinite loop?  I dont even see a loop in your code...

Comment: @maccettura because as a result I get infinite 200 OK replies with "Message" as a text. I expected that after context.Done(this) I won't get any more messages from the bot. I send 1 message to bot and I expect 1 response. I added to the question other screenshot, so I hope it's more clear.

Comment: please post your entire `RootDialog.cs`  Also, what are you trying to accomplish here, what is your use case for using the `StartAsync` method?  I'm confused because this shouldn't even compile

Comment: @JasonSowers I added the information you requested to the question

Comment: nevermind it should compile, but still I'm confused why you are trying to use the StartAsync method

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but to send a welcome message you just need to check for the `ConversationUpdate` activity type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823446/when-user-sends-message-to-my-bot-he-receives-welcome-message-but-when-user-re

Comment: Please post more code, I dont see a loop anywhere in your code.