# Showing Authentication after immediate welcome message

Tags: botframework

I am using AuthBot for authentication user. Now I have updated my ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate with welcome message and it's working perfectly fine and after welcome by entering any user input (hi or hello) I am getting Authentication option. But, I need to show the authentication part after immediate welcome message. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Add your existing Authentication option directly in the conversation update?

Comment: @NicolasR ... Yeah I did the same, but getting authentication option twice. To overcome this I put the whole welcome message part in else condition of Post method in MessageController. Not sure, whether its a correct approach or not, as part of R & D, got a work around.

Comment: I think you should have a look to the answer of this one to solve the fact that you got 2 authentication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823446/when-user-sends-message-to-my-bot-he-receives-welcome-message-but-when-user-re

Comment: For a final conclusion: 1. Working Code - https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine/DirectLineBot/Controllers/MessagesController.cs

Comment: we recommend using [BotAuth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth) over AuthBot. glad you found a solution though!